# Scriptmanager register javascript not working inside event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, scriptmanager, sqldependency

i 'm using `SqlDependency` for a real-time ASP.NET application. And i'm using some javascript methods on my almost whole project that i can register with ScriptManager like:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), new Random().Next(0, 9999999).ToString(), "alert('Some Text');", true);
```

this works everywhere expect inside Onchange event of SqlDependency like:

```
 SqlDependency dep = new SqlDependency(sqlCommand);
 SqlDependency.Start("my_con_str");
 dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dep_OnChange);
 void dep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
 {
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), new Random().Next(0, 9999999).ToString(), "alert('TEST');", true);
 }
```

above code doesn't work. But anywhere expect inside of `dep_OnChange` event `RegisterStartupScript` is working perfectly.. By the way i tried almost whole register methods of `ScriptManager` and `ClientScript` nothing worked..

*Note: And i'm pretty sure it's not about SqlDependency it's about events like onChange..*

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's going to work, because the ScriptManager needs the Http Context to work; internally, it is using that to access the request/response lifecycle.  Since the dependency can change OUTSIDE of that lifecycle, the ScriptManager won't be able to be instantiated because it only works while IN the lifecycle.  That is the problem with statics and stateless ASP.NET.

The only real option is to consider a polling mechanism on the client side, or check out [HTML 5 server side events with ASP.NET](http://www.worldwidewhat.net/2011/07/using-server-sent-events-with-asp-net/), or even HTML 5 web sockets.

Comment: you mean sqldependency can change lifecycle ? and i'm pretty OK with SQLDependency it's showing whole changes on_change event, i don't want to change it. isn't there another solution ?

Comment: ScriptManager can only be used when the server is processing a page postback.  That is the only scenario it works; sql dependency does not care about ASP.NET, and as such, you have to poll for changes in client javascript.